# Django creates migration files after each 'makemigrations' because of set?

Tags: python, django, dictionary, database-migration

I've noticed strange things in my Django project. 
Each time I run `python manage.py makemigrations` command new migration file for my app called notifications is created. I did ***zero changes*** to the model, but the new migration file is created. I can run makemigrations command N number of times and N number of migration files will be created.

The model looks as following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import EmailField


class EmailLog(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=False)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    html_body = models.TextField(null=False)
    sent_choices = {
        ('OK', 'Sent'),
        ('KO', 'Not sent'),
        ('KK', 'Unexpected problems')
    }
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=sent_choices,
                              null=False, default='KO')
    sent_log = models.TextField(null=True)
    sent_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False)
```

Each migration just swaps the position of `sent_choices` field. that's all!

Is it because `sent_choices` has a *random* order? How do I avoid it?

Comment: That's not a dictionary, it's a set literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right - it is because of the [set](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set#set), which is unordered.

I would recommend using a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple) instead.

```
sent_choices = (
    ('OK', 'Sent'),
    ('KO', 'Not sent'),
    ('KK', 'Unexpected problems')
)
```

A tuple is also used in [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices).